# How can I compare two (not necessarily integer) variables?

Tags: tex-core

After experimenting and researching for hours, I still cannot figure out how to perform a simple equality test between two numbers.

More specifically, here, the two numbers in question are the argument to my `\abc` command (`#1`) and my `\test` variable.

This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't produce the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\test{0.5}

\newcommand{\abc}[1]{
\ifnum #1=\test
  Something % do something
\fi}

\abc{0.5} % does something
\abc{0.7} % does nothing

\end{document}
```

Please help me with this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`\ifnum`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/ifnum) can be used to compare numbers, but only if the latter are integers. However, you can use [`\ifdim`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/ifdim) to compare fixed-point number. Note that you need to specify some unit (such as `pt`), though.

You probably want a more general command like the one I've defined below (`\equalitytest`), which compares the values of two arbitrary fixed-point numbers. You can always define your `\abc` command based on my `\equalitytest` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand\equalitytest[2]
{%
    Is #1\ equal to #2?
    \ifdim#1pt=#2pt
        Equal.\\
    \else%
        Not equal.\\
    \fi%
}

\begin{document} 
\equalitytest{0.5}{0.5}
\equalitytest{0.7}{.8}

\def\test{0.5}
\newcommand\abc[1]
{%
    \equalitytest{#1}{\test}
}
\abc{0.9}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: Direct answer to Pygmalion's post:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\test{0.5}

\newcommand{\abc}[1]{
\ifdim#1 pt=\test pt
  Something % do something
\fi}

\abc{0.5} % does something
\abc{0.7} % does nothing

\end{document}
```

Comment: I must commend you for your effort, but the final version of your answer just does not respond to my question, which was comparing a parameter of the function (#1) to a global value (\test).  In fact, the answer to my question is as simple (\ifdim\test pt=#1 pt) as I was dumb not to find it myself.  I suggest you edit your answer in a way that responds to my question (not deleting \equality test) and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pygmalion You can *commend* me all you want, but I accept *commands* from nobody :)

Comment: I recommend `\newcommand*\equalitytest[2]{\ifnum#1pt=#2pt \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}` which can be used as `\equalitytest{<f1>}{<f2>}{<true>}{<false>}`. (Though, there are many packages that provide such macros.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I like this solution.  And I don't like to load the whole package of 200 lines for just two lines

Answer (score 10):

[Jubobs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131877/16967) shows, how TeX dimensions can be used to compare fixed point numbers. There are two limitations:

- The largest TeX dimension is `\maxdimen` = 16383.99998pt = 16384pt - 1sp.
  TeX will complain with `! Dimension too large`, if larger values are tried.
- The smallest TeX dimension is 1sp = 2<sup>-16</sup>pt ≈ 0.00001525878906pt.

As jfbu pointed out in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/how-can-i-compare-two-not-necessarily-integer-variables/133437?noredirect=1#comment929117_133437), the largest unit `in` does not give an higher precision for the fractional part than the standard unit `pt` because of the rounding of the fractional part to multiples of 2<sup>-16</sup> ≈ 0.000015258789 due to TeX's scanning of the number.

The other extreme is unit `sp` that ignores the fractional part. But the number can go up to 2<sup>30</sup>-1 = 1073741824.

### Package `fp`

Package `fp` implements macro based fixed point arithmetic. From its `readme`:

> ```
> Fixed point arithmetic for TeX with numbers ranging from
>    -999999999999999999.999999999999999999
> to
>    +999999999999999999.999999999999999999
> ```

The following example implements the comparison of fixed point numbers using package `fp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp-basic}
\makeatletter
% \equalnumsthenelse{<number A>}{<number B>}{<then: A=B>}{<else: A≠B>}
\newcommand*{\equalnumsthenelse}[2]{%
  \FPifeq{#1}{#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\test{0.5}

\newcommand*{\abc}[1]{
  \equalnumsthenelse{#1}{\test}{%
    \[#1=\test\]%
  }{%
    \[#1\ne\test\]%
  }%
}

\abc{0.5}
\abc{0.7}
\abc{0.500000000001}
\abc{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In opposite to a simple `\ifdim`, this method is not expandable because of `\FPifeq`.

Comment: It is false that using `in` brings the maximal precision for the fraction part. In fact the fractional part, independently of the unit, is rounded to an integer multiple of 1/65536. cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338510/4686

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to be considered is `l3fp`, included in `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompare}{ m m m }
 {
  % #1 = test to perform
  % #2 = text for the true case
  % #3 = text for the false case
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\test{0.5}
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
  \fpcompare{#1=\test}{Something}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\verb|\abc{0.5}|: X\abc{0.5}X

\verb|\abc{0.7}|: X\abc{0.7}X

\verb|\abc{0.500000000001}|: X\abc{0.500000000001}X

\verb|\abc{1234567890}|: X\abc{1234567890}X

\edef\TEST{\fpcompare{0.5 = 0.5}{Equal}{Different}}\texttt{\meaning\TEST}\\
\TEST

\edef\TEST{\fpcompare{0.7 = .8}{Equal}{Different}}\texttt{\meaning\TEST}\\
\TEST

\fpcompare{3.141529653 = 355/113}{Equal}{Different}

\fpcompare{3.141529653 != 355/113}{Different}{Equal}

\fpcompare{2.718281828459045 = 2718.281828459045/1000}{Equal}{Different}

\end{document}
```

One can test for equality with `<fp1> = <fp2>`, strict inequality with `<fp1> < <fp2>` or `<fp1> > <fp2>`, non strict inequality with `<fp1> <= <fp2>` or `<fp1> >= <fp2>`, inequality with `<fp1> != <fp2>`.

In the example code, I show that the test is fully expandable. Consult `interface3.pdf`, part XXI for more information about the syntax of `<fp>` and size limitations.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To compare arbitrarily big decimal rational numbers (for example `3.141592` versus `2.1782817828`) you could use package [xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

Particularly since `1.09a (2013/09/24)` it provides `\xintifEq{A}{B}{<do this if A=B>}{<do that if A\neq B>}`.

Here `A` and `B`  may be (big) integers, decimal numbers (with scientific part), or fractions, or macros expanding to such things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}

\newcommand*\equalitytest[2]{%
    \xintifEq{#1}{#2}{#1 is equal to #2}{#1 is unequal to #2}%
}%

\begin{document}

\equalitytest{3.141529653}{355/113}

\equalitytest{2.718281828459045}{2718.281828459045/1000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### original answer (before addition of `\xintifEq` to `xintfrac`)

`\xintCmp{A}{B}` returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` if `A<B`, `A=B`, `A>B`. `A` and `B` may be decimal numbers, or fractions, or macros expanding to such things.

And `\xintSgnFork{\x}{I}{II}{III}` does `I` if `\x` expands to `-1`, `II` if `0`, and `III` if `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}

% arguments may be decimal numbers such as 3.14
% or fractions such as 355/113

% this is an expandable command
% (its arguments may be macros expanding to the numbers or fractions)

\newcommand*\equalitytest[2]{%
    \xintSgnFork{\xintiAbs{\xintCmp{#1}{#2}}}% -1 converted into 1
    {}% -1: does not happen
    {equal}%   \xintCmp returned 0
    {unequal}% \xintCmp returned -1 or 1.
}%

\begin{document}

\equalitytest{3.141529653}{355/113} (355/113=\xintTrunc{10}{355/113}...) %unequal

\equalitytest{2.718281828459045}{2718.281828459045/1000} % equal


\end{document}
```

[image: comparison]