# Why pdf file cannot be reproduced?

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I'm striking with an interesting problem. I created a pdf file long time ago. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3ap37f68hoqg8f/cweave-old.pdf?dl=1).
Now just to recall how it was generated I decided to repeat the process and compare pdf files.
I'm getting close, but I can't make the old and new pdf files look the same.
I remember that I did everything in a usual way, I just changed the margins.

Why the pdf file can't be reproduced?

This is the process to generate new pdf file:

1) Get the latest cweb sources from ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/cweb/cweb-3.64ah.tgz

2) In `cwebmac.tex` change `{NOS} fith` to `{NOS} fitb` manually or with this command

```
perl -i -pe 's/{NOS} fith/{NOS} fitb/' cwebmac.tex
```

3) Add the following to the end of `cwebmac.tex`

```
\let\Blue=\Black
\hoffset=1.52400970458984374999999999999cm
\pageshift=2in
\advance\pageshift by-\hoffset
\advance\hoffset by-1in
\advance\pageshift by-1in
```

4) Build `cweave`

```
touch *.c
make
```

5) Run `cweave` on `cweave.w`

```
./cweave cweave.w
```

6) Generate the pdf file:

```
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=1460880679 pdftex cweave.tex
```

7) Now we compare old pdf with new pdf. For this we must uncompress objects in pdf files.

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable cweave.pdf cweave-long.pdf
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable cweave-old.pdf cweave-old-long.pdf
diff -u cweave-old-long.pdf cweave-long.pdf
```

We see in the diff that in new pdf a lot of values are less by exactly 0.001 than in old pdf.
But I can't make this 0.001 disappear. If I set `\hoffset` to `1.52400970458984375`,
the values in new pdf is by `0.001` greater than in old pdf. And if I set `\hoffset`
to `52400970458984374999999999999`, the values are by `0.001` less in new pdf than in
old pdf. I'm completely puzzled by this. Also, I remember to have set `\hoffset` to something simple, like `1.5cm`, not this value which I constructed empirically by repeatedly comparing the diff.

Also, some hyphenation is changed. For example, the following is different in old and new pdf files:

```
-/F13 9.9626 Tf 125.8 495.045 Td [(i)]TJ/F3 7.9701 Tf 13.837 0 Td [(Used)-354(in)-354(secti)-1(o)1(n)]TJ
+/F13 9.9626 Tf 125.799 495.045 Td [(i)]TJ/F3 7.9701 Tf 13.837 0 Td [(Used)-354(in)-354(se)-1(ction)]TJ
```

i.e., how is

```
[(Used)-354(in)-354(secti)-1(o)1(n)]TJ
```

different from

```
[(Used)-354(in)-354(se)-1(ction)]TJ
```

? But, more importantly, *why* it is different? What this pdf code means, anyway?

Why `pdftex` can't reproduce the pdf file?

This is the link to download the diff file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvbijcn2689cuye/cweave.diff?dl=1

Comment: What is the purpose of step 2?  How does it affect the comparison if you leave it out?

Comment: @HenriMenke this change brings cwebmac.tex to the state in which it was when old pdf file was created, in order to remove irrelevant information from the diff of old and new pdf files

Comment: 1) dropbox requires to register for download, 2) does the old pdf info dict have information on how it was produced (pdftex or ps2pdf or...), which version of pdftex ? cm-super ?

Comment: @jfbu No need to register - just click "No thanks, continue to view" at the bottom of registration form. BTW, which site do you use to store files for download?

Comment: 1) I can view it but I click download it does ask again to register 2) my internet provider allows me to create a home page and if I need to share a file I upload it there and give people the link. I don't use and don't like social networks or cloud business.

Comment: @jfbu the cweb-3.64ah.tgz link does not work for some reason. Use `git clone https://github.com/ascherer/cweb`

Comment: correction: you are right that there is at bottom a "no thanks, I wish to go ahead with download" (translated from French). Sorry for noise. Sorry also because I am off to work now, hence that was double noise.

Comment: @jfbu the file was created with default pdfTeX version `1.40.16` and CM-fonts

Comment: The thing you added to the end of `cwebmac.tex` (the `\advance` etc.) seems quite arbitrary; is it something "standard" or something you came up with? What is its purpose? Also, what is the reason to set `\hoffset` and `\pageshift` by giving them initial values and modifying them immediately, rather than directly giving them the desired values?

Comment: In other words, the effect of that code is (logically) to set `\hoffset` to `1.52400970458984374999999999999cm - 1in` and `\pageshift` to `2in - 1.52400970458984374999999999999cm - 1in`. This will correspond to some number of "points" or rather "scaled points", in TeX. (Note that there may be conversion issues, e.g. 2.54cm and 1in may not be exactly equal.) You may have better luck just setting those two values on two different lines (possibly directly as an integer number of "sp" units), rather than trying to affect them indirectly via multiple commands. (But my earlier questions remain.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR TeX considers dimension unit as scale factors but indeed 2.54cm and 1in  do not give the exact same number  of `sp` units. But if you multiply by 100, i.e. `254cm` vs `100in` you have exact identity.

Comment: @jfbu Yes that's what I was getting at. The effect of the OP's commands is to set `\hoffset=-1894511sp \pageshift=1894512sp` in one case, and `\hoffset=-1894482sp \pageshift=1894483sp` in the other. Somewhere in these ranges there may be pairs of values which will produce the results the OP wants, and if we know what those (ranges of) acceptable values are, we may have better luck reverse-engineering what are the likely "natural" units which may have led to those values.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR agreed. See my answer (``0.6in``)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### final addition: when does `<foo> cm = <bar> in` hold for TeX ?

passing mathematical details and *barring mathematical oversight in my **quick** investigation* it is necessary and sufficient that the rounding of `<foo>` to an entire multiple `f/65536` of `1/65536` gives an `f` which is multiple of `127`.

Then and only then is there some `<bar> in` which gives exactly the same TeX dimension. And the rounding of `<bar>` to an integral multiple `g/65536` of `1/65536` will be with `g` a multiple of `50`. And vice versa.

Example: we seek such a dimension nearby `0.6in`. We need a multiple of `50` nearby `0.6*65536=39321.6`, hence `39300` or `39350`. The former is obtained via `0.59967in` (and decimals nearby) and the latter via `0.60043in` (and decimals nearby).

In fact, for TeX we have exactly

> - `0.59967in = 1.52316cm = 2840211sp`
> - `0.60043in = 1.52510cm = 2843824sp`

```
\number\dimexpr0.59967in\relax =\number\dimexpr1.52316cm \relax

\number\dimexpr0.60043in\relax =\number\dimexpr1.52510cm \relax

\bye
```

[image]

But, as is the main cause of the OP, `0.6in` has no exact equivalent using `cm` unit. In terms of `sp` units the possible `N sp` which admit both a representation as `<foo> in` and `<bar> cm` are those with `N = int(3613.5*k)` for some integer `k`. Above, `k` is respectively `786` and `787`.

### update: explanation how TeX scans dimensions

It has been clarified below and in comments that the cause of the difference was in the fact that you used formerly `in` as dimension units, and in your reconstruction attempt were using rather `cm`. Further, it is not exactly the same to make the difference between two dimensions originally expressed in `in` and to specify directly the result in `in`'s because `1in` is not an integral number of `sp`, the smallest unit used by TeX.

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231281/4686 I explained how TeX handles dimensions like `abc.xyz... pt`. This is from §452 of `tex.pdf` (texdoc tex.pdf). Turns out that part is reused also for `abc.xyz... in`, hence I recall the result:

> 1. the fraction abc.xyz... is rounded (the rounding being away from zero) to an integral multiple of 1/65536
> 2. in this process, the algorithm may discard (without affecting the theoretical result) all except the first 17 digits after the decimal mark.

Let's say that we have the "unpacked" result in the form of a pair `(n, f)` which represents at this stage the fraction `(65536n+f)/65536`.

Now TeX takes into account the dimension unit. This is explained at §458 of `tex.pdf`. The easy case is `pt` (which was handled earlier at §453), TeX simply puts `65536*n+f` in the register. For the case of `in`, we morally need to do `(65536*n+f)*7227/100`. Of course the issue here is to not create overflows with integer arithmetic. The routine which does that is at §107. Let us write `x=65536*n+f`. The operations (simplified here, no signs, no overflow intercept) are

> t<- (x mod 32768)*7227
>
> u<- (x div 32768)*7227 + (t div 32768)
>
> v<- (u mod 100)*32768 + (t mod 32768)
>
> RESULT<- 32768*(u div 100) + (v div 100)

**clarification** *to be very precise TeX applies this routine not to the integer `x=65536 n + f`, but to the (half-word) integer `n`, and the routine above also returns the "remainder" `v mod 100`, which is then appropriately combined with `f` and the scale `7227/100`, so that almost up to the end data is maintained in shape `(N, F)` representing `N + F/65536` where the exact `F` has been truncated to an integer; and at the very last step the `attach_fraction` sub-routine puts `y = 65536*N+F` into the register. But this final integer `y` is exactly as if the procedure above had been applied to `x = 65536 n +f`. Which would not be possible directly due to arithmetic overflows.*

Following steps `x = 32768 q + r`, `t = 7227r`, `u=7227q + int(7227r/32768) = 7727x/32768 - 7227r/32768 + int(7227r/32768)` which mean that `u` (which is an integer) `=7227x/32768 - d` with `0<= d < 1`. Hence `u = int(7227x/32768)`. Writing `u =100*(u div 100) + (u mod 100) = 100*(RESULT/32768 - (v div 100)/32768) + (v/ 32768 - (t mod 32768)/32768) = 100*RESULT/32768 + (v mod 100)/32768 - (t mod 32768)/32768`, we get `RESULT = x*7227/100 - 32768*d/100 - (v mod 100)/100 + (t mod 32768)/100`. But the `d` was `t/32768 - int(t/32768)` = `(t mod 32768)/32768`, in fact. Thus all simplifies to `RESULT= x*7227/100 - (v mod 100)/100`. As `RESULT` is an integer, and as `x*7227` is an integer, this means that, exactly, `RESULT` is the truncation of `x*7227/100`to an integer.

We can sum up the whole thing into:

> 1. first *round* the decimal `abc.xyz..` into an integral multiple `x` of `1/65536`. In doing this we need keep only 17 fractional digits of the input.
> 2. multiply by conversion factor `72.27` and then *truncate* to an integral number of `sp` units.

Ah, damn'd I wanted to illustrate the `cm` thing. Well then the conversion factor from §458 is `7227/254` and all of the above with `100` replaced by `254` goes through.

Let's look thus at `1.52400970458984374999999999999cm`. First we need only 17 digits after decimal mark. Count digits and see we can simplify input to `1.52400970458984374`. Then we need to multiply by `65536` and round. Take your preferred engine. Some like things like Maple, etc.. others enjoy `xint`.

```
$ rlwrap etex -jobname worksheet
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=etex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**xintexpr.sty
entering extended mode
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintexpr.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintfrac.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xint.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintkernel.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xinttools.sty))
*\def\x #1;{\message{\xinttheiexpr[40] #1\relax}}% (this rounds)

*\x 65536*1.52400970458984374;
99877.4999999999993446400000000000000000000000
*\x 65536*1.52400970458984375;
99877.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000
*
```

we are at a border case here, and the first case gives `99877`. Then we do the second step which is `99877*7227/254`:

```
*\x 99877*7227/254;
2841775.9015748031496062992125984251968503937008
```

which we must truncate: the result is `2841775sp`.

In the second case we get first via rounding `99878`, and then we must evaluate `99878*7227/254`:

```
*\x 99878*7227/254;
2841804.3543307086614173228346456692913385826772
```

hence the result is `2841804sp`.

Let's now take the case of the `0.6 in` specification. We repeat the above. First `0.6*65536=39321.6` is rounded to `39322`. Then `39322*7227/100 = 2841800.94` is truncated to `2841800sp`.

You will find all these values below.

For the record `1.4in`: `1.4*65536=91750.4`, rounded to `91750` then `91750*7227/100=6630772.5` is truncated to `6630772sp`.

---

---

this is not an answer but is too long for a comment

were you using `cm` as dimension unit back then ?

**edit** I think you were using `0.6in`. See at bottom.

there is a (surprising to me currently because I have completely forgotten the details of TeX input process for dimensions at this stage) sensibility to using `cm` as dimension unit.

```
{

\dimen2=1.52400970458984374999999999999cm

\number\dimen2

\dimen2=1.52400970458984375cm

\number\dimen2

\dimen2=1.52400970458984374cm

\number\dimen2

}


\input xintexpr.sty

\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984374999999999999*72.27/2.54*65536\relax

\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984375*72.27/2.54*65536\relax


\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984374*72.27/2.54*65536\relax


\bye
```

[image]

---

Update:

```
{

\dimen2=1.52400970458984374999999999999cm

\number\dimen2

\dimen2=1.52400970458984375cm

\number\dimen2

\dimen2=1.52400970458984374cm

\number\dimen2

}


\input xintexpr.sty

\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984374999999999999*72.27/2.54*65536\relax

\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984375*72.27/2.54*65536\relax


\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984374*72.27/2.54*65536\relax


\number\dimexpr 2.54cm\relax


\number\dimexpr 1in\relax


\number\dimexpr 254cm\relax


\number\dimexpr 100in\relax



\xinttheiexpr [50] 1.52400970458984374/2.54\relax


{

\dimen2=0.6in

\number\dimen2

}

\bye
```

[image]

```
% TeX value

{

\dimen2=0.6in

\number\dimen2

}

% exact value:

\xinttheiexpr [10] 0.6*72.27*65536\relax

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you concluded 0.6 in: does it give the same results as the OP's PDFs? (I haven't checked, and I don't see a mention in the answer…) Or are you saying that "0.6 in" is what is most likely the OP wrote instead of "1.52400970458984374999999999999cm"? (If the latter, nice find, and probably the right guess! Not sure if that will solve the OP's mystery though.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I agree with `\hoffset=0.6in`. Then the annotation rectangles are the same.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the second: I just (belatedly ;-) ) converted Igor's amazing `cm` spec into `in` unit and it turned out very close to `0.6in`. That's all !

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek do you know the reason of the other differences? This is the new diff https://www.dropbox.com/s/0s5yqihl7cvoxwz/cweave2.diff?dl=1

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The differences look like tiny rounding issues. If you want to debug it, then both pdfTeX versions (1.40.16 and 1.40.17) are needed as well as other files needed to compile the example (fonts, ...). If the old file can be reproduced with the older versions, then experiments can be done (e.g., running the newer pdfTeX on the old files, running the older pdfTeX on the new files, ...) to figure out, which component is responsible for the rounding changes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Except the rounding there is strange hyphenation differences - see in the bottom of OP. Now with `\hoffset=0.6in` the difference of `0.001` disappeared from the diff of pdf files, but there is new complication: in ps file all values are exactly by `0.001` greater. How to remove this difference? (I convert `cweave-old.pdf` and `cweave.pdf` via `pdf2ps`) This is the link to the ps diff https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6jgcifl0u9f2ql/cweave-ps.diff?dl=1

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek pdfTeX is not the issue - the problem is in `cwebmac.tex`. This is the link to another old pdf file which was created at the same time as the first old pdf file https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6a2jhted2f14kc/cweave-old-default.pdf?dl=1 Compare it with pdf file generated the same way as described in OP, but without changing cwebmac.tex. Now the pdf files and ps files do not differ. So, the reason is only somewhere in cwebmac.tex. How to figure it out based on the diff of the pdf files?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Why don't you diff the `cwebmac.tex` files? Which versions of that file are you comparing?

Comment: @cfr that's the point - I don't have the old `cwebmac.tex` file. I want to recreate it based on comparing the resulting pdf files.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko But why? Why not get a copy of the relevant file? Even if you don't know the version for sure, you must be able to estimate from the PDF compilation date. I doubt this file has undergone frequent radical changes. In the decade between 2006 and 2016, the file was revised only once with only 4 changes aside from the lines bumping the version.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It is done! Strangely enough, when I replaced `\pageshift=2in \advance\pageshift by-\hoffset` with `\pageshift=1.4in` all the remaining differences disappeared altogether. But why?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The smallest unit is 1 sp in TeX. Unhappily, 1 in is *not* a multiple of 1 sp, therefore rounding occurs. Compare 9472573 sp (2 in) - 2841800 sp (.6 in) = 6630773 sp (2 in - 0.6 in) with 6630772 sp (1.4 in).